# C segmentation fault linked list

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

For school I have to implement a pop function to a linked list. But when I run it I get a segmentation fault and I have no idea why... I already debugged it and it points me to *value = current->next;
I'm very new to C so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Note: I had to implement much more functions beside pop. So every other function call you see here, is already implemented and works correct.

*list.h*

```
int list_pop(struct List* list, int* value);
```

*list.c*

```
int list_pop(struct List* list, int* value)
{
    struct ListNode* curr = list->first;
    struct ListNode* prev;

if (curr == NULL)
    return 0;

while (curr != NULL)
{
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
}

*value = curr->value;   **Debugger says that in this line there is something wrong.**
prev->next = NULL;
free(curr);
return 1;
```

Thank you in advance, also it would be very cool if someone could tell me if this pop function is correct :)

Comment: For starters, the while loop right before that line only terminates if `current == NULL`. Which means that `current` is guaranteed to be `NULL` at that line. Which means you probably shouldn't dereference it.

Comment: this line: while (current != NULL) means that current is already past the end of the list.  However, previous points to the last entry in the list.  So use previous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (current != NULL)
{
    previous = current;
    current = current->next;
}

*value = current->value;
```

At the end of your while loop, current is NULL.

You want to iterate while there is a next element.
Therefore, you should replace it by

```
while (current->next != NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (current != NULL)
```

So this while loop will terminate when `current` is NULL. Wonderful! Now, what's the next thing that's going to happen?

```
*value = current->value;
```

Well, current is now NULL. Dereferencing the NULL pointer will make the debugger very sad.